# CoordinatorLayout and a layout GONE

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I'm trying to use a CoordinatorLayout to move out of the screen 3 layouts when the user scroll on a RecyclerView.

My view contain 3 linearLayout on the top and a recyclerView on the Bottom.

The scroll and view animations are perfect!

Now, i would like to remove the second linearLayout (after user action).

When the layout is GONE, the view is visually updated correctly except for the scroll. The scroll "limits" are the same as before the view is GONE. So i have an offset of the GONE layouts height when i scroll up.

Do you have an idea why? Is it possible to ask the CoordinatorLayout to refresh his scrolling limits ?

Here is an XML representation:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>

        <LinearLayout
            // Would like to remove this layout.
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"/>

        <LinearLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: maybe invalidate the CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: I already tried it. But i found the solution ! :p You have to remove the view from the AppBarLayout like this : REMOVE : get the child index : mAppBarLayoutIndex = mAppBarLayout.indexOfChild(YOUR LAYOUT); and remove it from the view : mAppBarLayout.removeView(YOUR LAYOUT); AND TO ADD : mAppBarLayout.addView(YOUR LAYOUT, mAppBarLayoutIndex); And it works. Thanks for your help !